# A simple javascript thing. But not able to make it work

Tags: javascript, html

A button is there. On click of that button, one more button should appear. That is happening. Code for that is

```
<button class="btn" onclick="showRawData();" id="url-keyvaleditor-actions-open">
    <i class="icon-edit"></i>POST
</button>

function showRawData(){
    document.getElementById('data').style.display='block';
}

<div id="data">
   <button class="btn" onclick="showRawTextArea();">raw</button>
</div>
```

On click on this `Raw` button, I should get a text area but that text area is not rendering. I have followed the same way as above to render that. But it is not working.

```
<button class="btn" onclick="showRawTextArea();">raw</button>
<div id="textAreaId">
   <textarea id="code-data-raw"></textarea>
</div>-

function showRawTextArea(){
    alert('raw text');
    document.getElementById('textAreaId').style.display='block';
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the wrong thing I am doing. Alert inside `showRawTextArea` is coming.

Comment: Did you try doing an inspect on the element and see what is happening??

Comment: Yes. I did inspect element. But there is no change in that after button click.

Comment: Works for me. How about you create a jsFiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: Is that literally the code? Because it doesn't contain any javascript code. All I see are HTML elements and normal text "function showRawTex...."

Comment: Please use a descriptive title. Also, what's up with the JavaScript there? No `<script>` tags? What have you done to debug the problem, except using `alert`? Where is the rest of your CSS? Elements are visible by default so I assume you must do something to hide them initially.

Comment: What code hides the "textAreaId" div in the first place?  Maybe there's CSS with an `!important` rule, or the opacity set to 0.  Or maybe your CSS is hiding the textarea itself instead of the containing div.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('code-data-raw').style.display = '';`, i.e. set it to empty string. Then the element will adopt its default or inherited style (the default for *textarea* and *button* is [*inline-block*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html)).

Comment: I'd put `document.getElementById('textAreaId').style.display='block';` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn" onclick="showRawData();" id="url-keyvaleditor-actions-open">
        <i class="icon-edit"></i>POST
        </button>
        <div id="data" style="display:none">
            <button class="btn" onclick="showRawTextArea();">raw</button>
        </div>
        <div id="textAreaId" style="display:none">
            <textarea id="code-data-raw"></textarea>
        </div>
        <script>
            function showRawData(){
            document.getElementById('data').style.display='block';
            }
            function showRawTextArea(){

            document.getElementById('textAreaId').style.display='block';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what was wrong with OP's code and the changes you made?